# Rails model: How to count (with filter) nested entities before saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a parent entity that contains children entities which are all created at the same time through nested attributes. On the parent entity, I have a callback before save that computes some data to store, based on the nested items. The problem is that `count` triggers a request to the database but entities don't exist yet so it returns 0. If it was just about counting, I'd use the `size` property, but I need to filter what I count on stuff itself computed in a callback... What's the best solution? See the example below.

PS: I know about `counter_cache` for the count but since I only create children through the parent, I prefer to compute it only once at the same time as the other property I compute.

```rb
class Parent < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :children
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :children

  before_save :update_total

  private

  def update_total
    self.total = children.size # OK, this works
    self.total_success = children.count(&:result) # Always 0 since it queries the DB
  end
end
```

```rb
class Child < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent

  before_save :update_result

  private

  def update_result
    self.result = check_result
  end
end
```

Comment: Si what would be the solution? I should have an after commit callback that calls `update` ?

Comment: @Eyeslandic so are you saving the parent twice in your case? You use `update` in your after save callback?

Comment: For now, I've found something that works exactly how I want:
```children.each { |child| self.total_success += 1 if child.result }
```

Comment: Yeah, I call `model.update_column(:total_success, 10)`, `update_column` doesn't trigger callbacks

Comment: That's a way to do it indeed... But I don't know if it's better to save twice than to do a `children.each` in the `before save` knowing that the children `before save` are called before the parent's one (I just tried it and it works)

Answer (score 0):

For now, I've found something that works: the children `before save` callback is called before the parent's one. I don't feel it's great but at least understandable.

I update the `total_result` this way:

```rb
self.total_success = 0
children.each { |child| self.total_success += 1 if child.result }
```